# HV000030: No validator could be found for type: java.math.BigDecimal

Tags: java, bigdecimal, spring-mvc-initbinders

I have a field: Ordinality
    DB: ORDINALITY        NOT NULL NUMBER(2)

```
@Column(name="ORDINALITY")
@NotNull(message="Ordinality is Mandatory")
@Size(max=2,message="Ordinality exceeded the limit, Max. 2 numbers are allowed.")
private BigDecimal ordinality;
```

> 1. I want to restrict the entry to numbers only, what will be the exact annotation syntax.
> 2. I am getting below error, when I am giving proper value as well as not giving any value and submit page.

```
javax.validation.UnexpectedTypeException: HV000030: No validator could be found for type: java.math.BigDecimal.
    at org.hibernate.validator.internal.engine.constraintvalidation.ConstraintValidatorManager.verifyResolveWasUnique(ConstraintValidatorManager.java:218)
    at org.hibernate.validator.internal.engine.constraintvalidation.ConstraintValidatorManager.findMatchingValidatorClass(ConstraintValidatorManager.java:193)
    at org.hibernate.validator.internal.engine.constraintvalidation.ConstraintValidatorManager.getInitializedValidator(ConstraintValidatorManager.java:97)
    at org.hibernate.validator.internal.engine.constraintvalidation.ConstraintTree.validateConstraints(ConstraintTree.java:125)
    at org.hibernate.validator.internal.engine.constraintvalidation.ConstraintTree.validateConstraints(ConstraintTree.java:91)
    at org.hibernate.validator.internal.metadata.core.MetaConstraint.validateConstraint(MetaConstraint.java:83)
    at org.hibernate.validator.internal.engine.ValidatorImpl.validateConstraint(ValidatorImpl.java:547)
```

Comment: what does ordinality mean here? if its simple 2 digit number, why are you storing it in BigDecimal?

Comment: JPA model class is system generated. It automatically took BigDecimal instead of long.

Answer (score 1):

To set precision of the underlying database field, you should use the precision and the scale elements of the `@Column` annotation.

```
@Column(precision=10, scale=2)
```

To validate the number use the `@DecimalMax` annotation.

```
@DecimalMax("30.00")
```

Comment: Thanks Milan, Is there any way we can give message for type mismatch ? Like user gives input as string instead of number, then it will display corresponding message.

Comment: Yes, check what messages Spring gives you (for example typeMismatch.YourModel.ordinality) and add custom values for it in your .properties messages file. Check out this [SO answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5738242/jsr-303-validation-with-custom-message).